# How to execute a function in parallel?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I am trying to call this function[1] in parallel. Therefore, I have created this function [2], and I call it like this [3][4]. The problem is that when I execute this code, the execution hangs and I never see the result, but if I execute `run_simple_job` in serial, everything goes ok. Why I can't execute this function in parallel? Any advice for that?

[1] function that I am trying to call

```
@make_verbose
def run_simple_job(job_params):
  """
  Execute a job remotely, and get the digests.
  The output will come as a json file and it contains info about the  input and output path, and the generated digest.

  :param job_params: (namedtuple) contains several attributes important for the job during execution.

        client_id (string) id of the client.
        command (string) command to execute the job
        cluster (string) where the job will run
        task_type (TypeTask) contains information about the job that will run
        should_tamper (Boolean) Tells if this job should tamper the digests or not
:return : output (string) the output of the job execution

"""
client_id = job_params.client_id
_command = job_params.command
cluster = job_params.cluster
task_type = job_params.task_type

output = // execute job

return output
```

[2] function that calls in parallel

```
def spawn(f):
  # 1 - how the pipe and x attributes end up here?
  def fun(pipe, x):
    pipe.send(f(x))
    pipe.close()

    return fun

def parmap2(f, X):
  pipe = [Pipe() for x in X]
  # 2 - what is happening with the tuples (c,x) and (p, c)?
  proc = [Process(target=spawn(f), args=(c, x))
        for x, (p, c) in izip(X, pipe)]

  for p in proc:
    logging.debug("Spawn")
    p.start()
  for p in proc:
    logging.debug("Joining")
    p.join()
  return [p.recv() for (p, c) in pipe]
```

[3] Wrapper class

```
class RunSimpleJobWrapper:
  """ Wrapper used when running a job """

  def __init__(self, params):
     self.params = params
```

[4] How I call the function to run in parallel

```
for cluster in clusters:
   task_type = task_type_by_cluster[cluster]

run_wrapper_list.append(RunSimpleJobWrapper(get_job_parameter(client_id, cluster, job.command, majority(FAULTS), task_type)))

jobs_output = parmap2(run_simple_job_wrapper, run_wrapper_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
n_jobs = -1 # use all the available CPUs
pool = Pool(n_jobs)

param_list = [...] # generate a list of your parameters


results = pool.map(run_simple_job,param_list)
```